# Python: decode russian string

Tags: python, decode, cp1251

I recieved a list of tuples from a mySQL database.
When I try to print an item, here is the result:

```
Ð”Ð°Ð»Ð¾ÐµÐ² ÐÐ»ÐµÐºÑÐ°Ð½Ð´Ñ€
<class 'str'>
```

This is cp1251, according to https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru

I have tried lots of variations of `.encode().decode()` with `errors='ignore'` params but without any success. Any ideas?

**UPD**
I recieve my list of tuples with `mysql-connector-python`.

`z` is the list. The result above is from `z[0][0]`

```
def select_name(add):
z = []
try:
    dbconfig = read_db_config()
    conn = MySQLConnection(**dbconfig)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select name from phone_add where ph_add = " + str(add) + ";")

    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row is not None:
        z.append(row)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
    return z

except Error as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

**Upd2**
Here is a wierd decoder.
Hope it will help smb.

I realised that the problem is in inserting to my DB. Will dig here.

```
q = string

codings = ['latin1', 'utf8', 'cp1251', 'unicode-escape', 'cp866']
exceptions = ['ignore', 'strict', 'xmlcharrefreplace', 'backslashreplace']
for i in codings:
    for j in codings:
        for z in exceptions:
            for p in exceptions:
                try:
                    print(q.encode(i, errors=z).decode(j, errors=p) + '<------' + i + ' ' + j + ' ' + z + ' ' + p)
                except:
                    pass
```

Comment: Please show the code which produced that.

Comment: I'm not so sure about your conclusion "this is CP1251". Using that same web page, I can view it in a variety of encodings, but none of them result in a complete readable "Russian" text.

Comment: I don't know how is it happening.
But after copying this string here, it's changing somehow, so I can't use it on this website. Very stange

Comment: Are you sure your database is OK? MySQL has some encoding-related issues. I didn't use MySQL since I quit PHP, but as far as I remember, you had to be sure that your database encoding and your connection encoding are the same.

Comment: Difficult question, don't know how to check this.
When I am logging in my database I see this values in an appropriate format

Comment: We don't know what you've tried, and how they failed.

Comment: so you think there is no point of trying to decode it?
I want to deal somehow with the existing result, hoped that's a shortest way, if not, will try to do smth with connector&DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in database.
The sting was already damaged during the insertion.
I tried `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` in my insertion script and everything went allright.